# active admin filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I Have a model page.rb and model comment.rb and comment belongs_to page.
Also i am using gem active admin. On index page i have a search form made by "filter", I have

```
  filter :country
  filter :city
  filter :category
  filter :description_type
  filter :title
  filter :sight_of_the_day, :as => :select
  filter :active, :as => :select
  filter :show_in_top, :as => :select
  filter :created_at
  filter :updated_at
```

it works fine, but i want to have 1 more filter. I want to make a checkbox named "comments" and if it is checked, i want to find pages only which have comments. How i can do this in active admin? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
filter :has_comments, :as => :select
```

This will generate select with options "Any", "Yes", "No". Also you need search method "has_comments_eq":

```
scope :has_comments_eq, lambda { |has| has == "true" ? with_comments : without_comments }
search_method :has_comments_eq
```

[search_method doc](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search/blob/master/lib/meta_search/method.rb#LC20)

Comment: In latest ActiveAdmin, MetaSearch has been replaced with Ransack so you'll need to use `ransacker` instead of `search_method`.  Here's an [example](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/blob/master/spec/support/schema.rb#L18).